# Visual Studio doesn't create localDB

Tags: entity-framework-4, visual-studio-2012, localdb

I am running Visual Studio 2012. I created 3 projects in my solution: data (with Entity Framework 5), console UI, and MVC4 UI. When I run console UI, everything works fine: the program accesses Local DB. However, when I am running MVC Project, I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot attach the file 'b:\Users\path-to-project\App_Data\DataAccess.MyContext.mdf' as database 'DataAccess.MyContext'.
```

I am comparing Web.config from MVC project with App.config from console project:

```
<configSections>    
<section name="entityFramework" 
         type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
         requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
```

and

```
<entityFramework>    
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

in both places. Why would MVC project *not* go to LocalDB?